# In R, how to estimate a polynomial function by Least Square method?

Tags: r, statistics, least-squares

```
n = 50
set.seed(100)
x = matrix(runif(n, -2, 2), nrow=n)
y = 2 + 0.75*sin(x) - 0.75*cos(x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.2)
```

[image: polynomial function to be estimated].

In R,
I want to estimate the above polynomial function by Least Square method.

Which means I want to know the estimate of γ0, γ1, γ2 and γ3.

And I also want to know the MSE under this estimator function.

I used this

```
summary(lm(y ~ x+ x^2+ x^3))
```

But just get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcqrk.png):

```r
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + (x^2) + (x^3))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.66448 -0.22251 -0.07694  0.20647  0.79429

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.54972    0.04761   32.55    <2e-16 ***
x            0.65279    0.04633   14.09    <2e-16 ***   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3319 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8053,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8013
F-statistic:  198.6 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Please tell me in R, what function or package can I use to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `summary(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)+ I(x^3)))` or `summary(lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))`.

Comment: Thank you, why it can work by just adding the ''I'' to (x^2) and (x^3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `I(.)` around your polynomials to indicate R that the `^` operator should be used rather as an arithmetical operator than a formula operator.

Let's create some example data to illustrate.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(100)
y <- x + x^2 + x^3 + rnorm(100)
```

What you want is this:

```
lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))$coe
# (Intercept)           x      I(x^2)      I(x^3) 
#  -0.4069207   3.4580770  -4.0516060   4.3227674
```

or:

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))$coe
# (Intercept) poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)1 poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)2 poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)3 
#  -0.4069207               3.4580770              -4.0516060               4.3227674
```

Without the `I(.)` the result is different,

```
lm(y ~ x + x^2 + x^3)$coe
# (Intercept)           x 
#  -0.6149136   3.3590395
```

because for some reason R interprets the forumla just as

```
lm(y ~ x)$coe
# (Intercept)           x 
#  -0.6149136   3.3590395 

all(lm(y ~ x)$coe - lm(y ~ x + x^2 + x^3)$coe == 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

However, consider:

```
lm(y ~ I(x + x^2 + x^3))$coe
# (Intercept) I(x + x^2 + x^3) 
#   -0.191611         1.141912
```

Creating a variable `z`

```
z <- x + x^2 + x^3
```

gives the same result:

```
lm(y ~ z)$coe
# (Intercept)           z 
#   -0.191611    1.141912
```

Or, more explicit, say we want to calculate the interaction `x` with `a`, we  want to use `*` as *formula*  operator:

```
a <- runif(100)
lm(y ~ x*a)$coe
# (Intercept)           x           a         x:a 
# -0.71920356  3.42008631  0.19180499 -0.07049342
```

When we use `*` as an *arithmetical* operator,

```
lm(y ~ I(x*a))$coe
# (Intercept)    I(x * a) 
#   0.5317547   2.7361742
```

the result is the same as:

```
xa <- x*a

lm(y ~ xa)$coe
# (Intercept)          xa 
#   0.5317547   2.7361742
```